# Approach for configmap and secret for a yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I have a `yaml` file which needs to be loaded into my `pods`, this `yaml` file will have both sensitive and non-sensitive data, this `yaml` file need to be present in a path which i have included as `env` in containers.

```
        env:
          - name:  CONFIG_PATH
            value: /myapp/config/config.yaml
```

If my understanding is right, the `configmap` was the right choice, but i am forced to give the sensitive data like password as plain text in the `values.yaml` in `helm` chart.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-config
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}-config
data:
  config.yaml: |

    configuration: 
      settings: 
        Password: "{{.Values.config.password}}"
        Username: myuser
```

`Values.yaml`

```
config:
  password: "mypassword"
```

Mounted the above config map as follows

```
        volumeMounts:
          - name:  {{ .Release.Name }}-config
            mountPath:  /myapp/config/
```

So i wanted to try `secret`, If i try secret, it is loading as `Environment Variables` inside pod, but it is not going into this `config.yaml` file.

If i convert the above `yaml` file into `secret` instead of `configmap` , should i convert the entire `config.yaml` into `base64` secret? my `yaml` file has more entries and it will look cumbersome and i dont think it as a solution.
If i take `secret` as a `stringdata` then the `base64` will be taken as it is.

How do i make sure that `config.yaml` loads into pods with `passwords` not exposed in the `values.yaml` Is there a way to combine `configmap` and `secret`
I read about `projected` volumes, but i dont see a use case for merging `configmap` and `secrets` into single `config.yaml`
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes has no real way to construct files out of several parts.  You can embed an entire (small) file in a ConfigMap or a Secret, but you can't ask the cluster to assemble a file out of parts in multiple places.

In Helm, one thing you can do is to put the configuration-file data into a helper template

```yaml
{{- define "config.yaml" -}}
configuration: 
  settings: 
    Password: "{{.Values.config.password}}"
    Username: myuser
{{ end -}}
```

In the ConfigMap you can use this helper template rather than embedding the content directly

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: { ... }
data:
  config.yaml: |
{{ include "config.yaml" . | indent 4 }}
```

If you move it to a Secret you do in fact need to base64 encode it.  But with the helper template that's just a matter of invoking the template and encoding the result.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata: { ... }
data:
  config.yaml: {{ include "config.yaml" . | b64enc }}
```

If it's possible to set properties in this file directly via environment variables (like Spring properties) or to insert environment-variable references in the file (like a Ruby ERB file) that could let you put the bulk of the file into a ConfigMap, but use a Secret for specific values; you would need a little more wiring to also make the environment variables available.

You briefly note a concern around passing the credential as a Helm value.  This does in fact require having it in plain text at deploy time, and an operator could `helm get values` later to retrieve it.  If this is a problem, you'll need some other path to inject or retrieve the secret value.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering this. Appreciate it. Accepted the answer.